# How to replace one char in Neovim?

Tags: neovim, replace, lazyvim

I used to use `s` for replacing one char with another. e.g.

- source: `"bla"`. command: `ss`. result: `"sla"`
- source: `"bla"`. command: `3ss`. result: `"s"`

Neovim (using LazyVim) seems to override this option, and I can't figure out how to restore it or what to use instead (`c` is fine, but replaces a full word, which complicates my workflow)

Comment: Does `3rs` work?

Comment: Please complain at LazyVims issue tracker, that they are overriding a system comand

Comment: @Friedrich it does. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome. FWIW, on Vim 9 or 8.2 I cannot get `3ss` to behave as described in the question.

Comment: @Friedrich you are right, my bad - `3ss` would substitute 3 chars with one `s`. Updating the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do use `r` instead

```
rs
```

Or

```
3rs
```